# POS UI design & development: what should be included & avoided?

Tags: user-interface, usability, point-of-sale

I'm having to design & develop UI for a Point of Sale (POS) system. 
There are obvious features that need to be included, like product selection & quantity, payment method, tender amount, user login (as many users will use one terminal), etc.

My question is related more towards the UI design aspect of developing this system. 
How should UI features/controls be positioned, sized? 
Is there a preferred layout? 
Are their colours I should be avoiding?

If you know of any resources to guide me, that would also help.

The reason this is critical to me as I am aware of the pressurized environment in which POS systems are used & I want to make the process as (i) quick, (ii) simple to use and (iii) result driven as possible for the user to service customers.

All answers, info & suggestions welcome.
Thanks.

P.s. If you could mention the "playoff" between controls that would also be appreciated (i.e. if touch screen a keypad control is provided, but if also supporting keyboard & mouse input how do you manage the keypad & UI space effectively?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Aggregated POS Design Guidelines**

Based on the above and other literature, here is my list of guidelines for POS design.
[it would be nice if we grew this list further]

User Performance Priorities (in order):
efficiency (least time to transaction conclusion)
effectiveness (accurate info & output)
user satisfaction (based on first 2 in work context)
learning time (reduce time to learn system by making it simple)

**GUIDELINES**

1. **Flexible Transaction Building** - don't force a sequence to transaction wher possible. Place product orders in any order & allow them to be changed to a point.
2. **Optimise Transaction Rate** - allow a user to complete a transaction as quickly as possible (least clicks are not really the issue as more clicks could mean larger value of transaction, which makes business sense)
3. **Support Handedness / Dexterity** - most users have a dominant hand and a weaker hand in terms of dexterity. Allow the UI to be customised (on a single click) for handedness. my example: a L->R / R->L toggle button which moves easy features like "OK", "Cancel" in nearer proximity to weaker hand.
4. **Constant Feedback** - provide snapshot feedback which describes current state of the transaction and calculated result of transaction (NB: accounts) before & after committing a transaction.
5. **Control "Volume"** - control volume refers to the colour saturation/contrast, prominence of positioning and size of a control. Design more frequently used controls to have larger "volumes" relative to less frequently used controls. e.g. "Pay" button larger than "cancel" button. E.g. High contrast & greater colour saturation increase volume.
6. **Target Findability** - finding & selecting targets (item, numeric key) is key to efficiency. Group related controls (close proximity), place controls on screen edges (screen edge traps pointer), emphasise control amplitude (this dimension emphasises users normal plain of motion) and colour coding make finding & selecting targets more efficient.
7. **Avoid Clutter** - too many options limits control volume and reduces findability.
8. **Use Plain Text** - avoid abbreviations as much as possible (only use standard abbreviations e.g. size: S, M, L, etc.). This is especially true for product lookup.
9. **Product Lookup** - support shortcuts for regular orders (i.e. burger meal), categorised browsing & item name search (least ordered items). Consider include a special item: this is any item where the user types what is wanted (i.e. specific whiskey order) - this requires pricing though.
10. **Avoid User Burden** - the user should be able to read answers to customer questions from the UI. So provide regularly requested/prioritised feedback for transaction (i.e. customer asks: "what will be the the outstanding balance on my account if I buy this item?" It should appear in UI already)
11. **Conversational Ordering** - customer drives the ordering not the system. So allows item selection to be non-sequential.
12. **Objective Focused** - the purpose of POS is to conclude the transaction from a business perspective. Always make transaction conclusion possible immediately with "Pay" button. If clicked, any incomplete items will be un-done: user then read order back before requesting cash/credit card)
13. **Personas** - there are different categories (personas) of users of POS systems like (i) Clerk/Cashier and (ii) Manager. The UI should present the relevant options to that logged-in persona according to these guidelines i.e. Cashier: large volume on transaction building controls; Manager: large volume on transaction/user management controls.
14. **Touch Screens** - (i) allow for touch input with generally larger controls to supported a large finger tip as pointer. (ii) Provide proprioceptive feedback - this is feedback that indicate the control pushed (it should have a short delay on it fade: user finger will be in the way initially). (iii) Auditory Feedback (optional) - this helps with feedback especially with regards errors in pressurised environment.
15. **User Training** - users must be trained to understand business protocol & how the POS supports that protocol. They are the one's driving the system. Also, speak to POS users to design & enhance your system - again they are experienced users of the POS system
16. **Context Analysis** - a thorough analysis of the context of use for your POS system should be performed to best implement the POS heuristics mentioned above effectively. Understanding the user (human factors), the tasks (frequency, duration, stress factors, etc.) and environment (lighting, hardware, space layout, etc.) should be comprehensively conducted during design and should not be assumed. Get your hands dirty & get into the users work space!! That way you can develop something your specific users can use effectively, efficiently and satisfactorily

I hope this helps everyone.

To all respondents, I really appreciate your feedback! Please give me more wrt to this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

A couple of thoughts from a couple of projects I've worked with:

- For the touch screen ensure that each button can be pressed by someone with "fat fingers" as easily as smaller ones (some layouts encourage the use of thumbs at particular locations). Also highlight each button when it is pressed (with a slow-ish fade if you have spare CPU cycles).
- Bigger grids are better than smaller ones. The numeric pad should always be in the same place (often the bottom right). The Enter/Tender/etc. "transaction" keys should be bigger than the individual numeric keys - (1) make it more obvious where it is, (2) it will be pressed more often than other screen areas and will wear out (a bigger area will last longer on average; this was more important with older style touch screens; newer technology is more resilient).
- Allow functions/SKUs to be reassigned to different grid positions; the layout that works well for one store will likely be wrong for a slightly different one.
- Group related functions by colour, but use excellent contrasts. Make sure that the fore/back combination looks good at all angles (some LCDs "bleed" colours left-to-right and/or top-to-bottom angles).
- Positive touch screen feedback with sounds needs to have configurable volume and sound sets. Muted tones might be better in an quieter upmarket store, but "perky" sounds are better in a clothing store with louder background music/noise, etc.
- Allow the grid size to be specified in percentages or "grid-block units" instead of pixels and draw everything with vectors, etc. since some hardware combinations may have LCDs with better resolution. (One system I worked on was originally specified as 640x480 but shipped at 1280x1024, so my design pre-planning saved a lot of rework later.)

And of course look at the ready-made solutions first (especially if you can get demo software/hardware for evaluation). Although they can be expensive they've often implemented a lot of things that'll you'll have to work through later, and may be cheaper in the long run, even after creating custom add-ons for your system.

**Also:**

Our UI supported a normal keyboard/mouse combo too (the touchable buttons were just standard button controls sized appropriately). If you pressed a number key it would trigger the same event as clicking the screen-pad button; other hotkeys were mapped to often used button commands (Enter, etc).

If run on a non-POS desktop (e.g. backoffice) the window could be resized too (the "POS desktop" maintained the same aspect ratio, adding dead space at the sides if needed). A standard top menu was available for additional administrative tasks, reporting, etc.

The design allowed everyone to build and test the UI before the associated hardware was finalized. And standard UI testing tools would work too.

**Even More:**

Our barcode scanners were serial/USB rather than keyboard-like, so each packet from the device raised a comms event. The selected "scanner type" driver class used the most secure formatting that the device could give us - some can supply prefix, suffix and/or checksum characters if programmed correctly - and then stripped this before handing the code up to the application.

The system made a "bzzzt" noise when the barcode couldn't be used (e.g. while cash drawer is open).

This design also avoided the need to set the keyboard focus to a specific entry area.

A tip: if the user is manually entering a barcode via the keypad, and hasn't completed it by pressing Enter, and then attempts to scan another barcode, it should beep instead, so the user can accept or cancel the pending item first.

Comment: @devstuff - see comment below

Comment: @devstuff: i have looked at screen shots from some other POS system. There are some shockers - but some common ideas. Thanks for that info.

Answer (score 5):

I ran across this question, and I thought I'd add my two cents since some of my work has been mentioned here.

I agree with most of what's been said, but it's important to remember that most everything mentioned represents *heuristics*.  That means that while they're good principles to follow, there are likely times when (a) specific rules should be broken, and (b) there will be contradictions between rules.  The trick is being able to weigh conflicting principles and apply them to the appropriate degrees (as you noted in a previous comment).

In the end, it's a matter of balancing the business requirements and user needs in a way that produces optimal results.  And in the real world, I find that this can never be achieved through heuristics alone.

Here's an example:  I recently finished POS designs for Subway, Wendy's, and Starbucks (see **Case Studies** at [POSDesigns.com](http://www.posdesigns.com/)).  All of these designs used solid heuristics, but all of them came out very, very different because of differences in the business goals and  requirements, the users' needs and background, the environment in which they work, the technology being used, and a whole host of other differences.

You can never create a great design in a vacuum.  For each of the clients mentioned above, I traveled around to a lot of different types of stores in multiple countries to get a feel for how the users' worked, how the systems would be used, how customers ordered, etc.  All this information - along with sales and other data provided by the company - was invaluable in creating a highly usable solution.

Here's another example: Guideline #3 you provide previously ("Support Handedness / Dexterity") is fine as a heuristic (though I have to say that I question the conclusion of swapping simply OK/Cancel).  But in visiting Subway stores, we discovered that in that context, the location of the register actually plays a greater role in the hand employees prefer.

In other words, registers that were squished against a wall on the right side tended to produce left-handed users, even when the users were right-handed for every other task.  This had implications for the way we allowed the UI to be flip-flopped...and who had control of it.  There are tons of examples like that, but we never could have achieved the gains that the user interfaces have produced - like 90% reduction in voids, near zero training, increased speed, accuracy, and check sizes, etc. - by following heuristics alone.

One more point (sorry...you've got me going now :-).  Many times heuristics are incomplete without more data as to how to apply them.  Consider your guideline #11, "Conversational Ordering".  There's much more to this guideline than just providing flexibility in order entry.  For instance, one of the many things you have to consider is that not all paths should be presented as equally probable.

We analyzed the way Starbucks' customers ordered in various locations across the United States and United Kingdom.  Then, we optimized the system for the most commonly spoken patterns.  If we had allowed all paths to have the same "volume", we would have sacrificed usability in other areas, since the design would have appeared more cluttered.  The new POS system now supports almost all possible order patterns, but the most probable paths are presented at a higher "volume" than those that are less probable.

OK, it turned out to be more than two cents, but the bottom line is this:  If you have a chance to visit the environments in which your POS will be used, analyze customer/employee interactions, etc. ...you should take it.  Contextual observations and analysis are invaluable in correctly applying heuristics to your situation.

Good luck!

Dr. Kevin Scoresby

FYI - I'd enjoy talking further about this if you or anyone else in the group would like.  My office phone number is on my "**About Us**" page at POSDesigns.com, or you can use the form to initiate an email conversation.  Feel free to call anytime during business hours U.S., East Coast Time.

Comment: Dr. Scoresby, thank you for commenting on this question. Its greatly appreciated. I come from the school of usability, so this critical part of the development cycle is always at the fore front of my thinking. You state the importance of contextual analysis, I totally agree. Contextual analysis is what helps to make a product truely usable: by understanding the user, their tasks and environment & designing for that. From what I've seen, the most costly & least usable products failed to perform context analysis during design. I've included this point above. FYI, I'll contact you.

Answer (score 4):

[Devstuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108799/pos-ui-design-development-what-should-be-included-avoided/1108970#1108970) already provides some great answers. In addition:

- Create a prototype design (can be simply color-printed on paper) and **test** this in a scenario that is as realistic as possible, i.e. in a store, with a real future user. Enact a few common scenarios and ask the user to really 'use' your prototype as he / she would use the final product. Obtain feedback through interview and observation.
- One way to evaluate your design is to check if you have applied the **CRAP principles** of design. [This article](http://usabilityfriction.com/2008/09/08/how-to-make-your-user-interface-crap/) discusses how this can relate to user interface design.

Comment: @devstuff: thanks for feedback. How do you playoff the UI layout between (i) touch screen supporting UI with Keypad versus (ii) keyboard+mouse supporting UI that doesn't require the keypad? My app needs to support both. From your experience did you design a UI for each?

Comment: @Daan: aah, some usability design techniques. I like the CRAP principles. They are fairly simple to implement & general. Have you applied them in POS design at all & found any principle issues? I've found that usability and UI principles apply differently depending on context.

Comment: @ForerMedia - I don't have experience with POS systems, so I cannot comment on usability principles that are specific to that kind of product. What do you mean by "principles apply differently depending on context"? In my experience, the *principles* can be applied the same regardless of context, only the resulting design may be different per context of course.

Comment: @Daan: sometimes principles counter each other depending on context. e.g. Nielsen has 2 principles: Flexibility and Consistency - these can conflict with each other and take on different prominence depending on context. So in POS, consistency would be more important than flexibility within the UI. Its a very simple example & these kind of issues become more prominent when you have to make a judgement call on specific UI features

Comment: +1 from me. Paper prototypes are a great idea (Carolyn Snyder's book has lots of great info)

Comment: Oops, the url for the book is http://www.paperprototyping.com/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has already been posted, here are some tips we picked up along the way.

We use two distinct UI's, one for touch-screen with large bold buttons and one for mouse/keyboard entry. the code behind them is the same just the layout is different.

**For touch screens**

Try not to have pop-up messages that take focus away from the main form, as users may not be looking at the screen, for example if they are chatting with the customer. we found that if this happen users will continues scanning products unaware that they are not been entered into the sale.

If using a bar code scanner be aware that they sometimes send an enter key after the bar code, that will active focused controls (saying yes/no to pop-ups). To help prevent this we disable the enter key-press on buttons, so only a mouse/finger press will fire the click event. we also turn tab stop to false (may be called different in you language), to stop controls that are touch only from getting focus.

As far as colours go we try to stick to bold button and font colours that can easily be distinguished/read in poorly lit rooms and on screens with glare, as most times users are not in the position to move the screen should they have problem reading it.

Anything you can do to speed up/ help the user is a good thing, for example on our payment screen, as well as having 0..9 keys for payment entry, we also have £1,£2,£5,£10 etc so users don't have to add up the money they are given, they can just press the key for each coin/note they received from the customer.

The best tip I can give is to remember that you are designing for a completely different environment form a desktop application, that would be used in an office. and that users may of never used a computer before. since POS systems are usually locked down, try to make it as easy to use out of the box as possible.

Comment: @Re0sless: I like the info on the contrasting. The POS i need to design will be used on standard office conditions but also in areas with bright sunlight - so glare is very likely

Comment: To all: what are your thoughts on the following article (just found it)?
http://news.zdnet.com/2100-9595_22-188129.html

Comment: All of Kevin's points are valid, especially the ones about staff needing to know business rules. As he says, not all orderable items are atomic (e.g. a sandwich) so the underlying system should know its component parts, to allow addition or removal.

Along with that, make room to show recent items in the order (e.g. last 5), before scrolling, to allow touch-to-activate-then-edit flows (scroll buttons are also better than scroll bars).

Comment: Adding to @Re0sless's tip about the glare: if your hardware supports adjusting the brightness/contrast/etc via software add that to a configuration page, accessible by a supervisor or manager. One store had issues with the afternoon sun in summer and had to regularly tweak these settings.

Answer (score 2):

another thing to consider is personas (as introduced in cooper's "the inmates are running the asylum").

essentially, you make up a few canonical "users".  give them names, hobbies, skills, a picture, and use them as the people you are designing for.

ie:

billy the cashier:  has some computer experience (playing on his ps2).  he's in high school, may go to community college.  he's a primary user of the system, and wants to be able to learn the new system quickly.

cyrus the manager:  needs to manage the cashiers.  needs a way, with only his authorization, void transactions and be able to review logs of the sales for making reports as well as managing "shrinkage" (theft).  he has 2 kids, lives out in the suburbs so has a 45 minute commute; therefore he doesn't want to spend extra time wrangling the system.

you may need three or four personas; any more than that and it becomes hard to design for.

I highly recommend the book "inmates are running the asylum", plus cooper wrote another book:  "about face"; which I have yet to read.

good luck!

Comment: @jill renee: thanks! I will need to go on-site where we intend deploying the POS and investigate the roles/personas. The POS has an international scope which makes it tough to get extensive personas - but some persona building is better than none.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing some sort of usability survey amongst your current user group.  There is no need for this to be a complicated or highly scientific survey.  Present them with simple questions to determine:

- The users priority when using the system (accuracy of task, speed, aesthetics)
- Preferred input devices
- Work flow through such a system
- Level of education and domain knowledge

I have found that a lot can be learnt from a simple survey like this and can be applied to your UI design to ensure that the users usability experience is satisfactory.

Comment: @bunn_online: I did a basic survey/interview with some users of another POS system just to get ideas. They basically said speed in transaction processing with critical & not having to perform any mental calculations to answer customer queries/justify transaction costs

based on that i have decided some aspects: (i) a pre-determined amount buttons for some purchases (i.e. for pre-paid items) and (ii) providing display of customers transaction in relation to account info (if any).

Comment: @ForerMedia: We had similar results in a survey that we performed.  Speed of transaction always came out tops.  This is probably because some of our POS users typically service 1000+ customers on a busy day.

Answer (score 1):

Great comments from everyone else.  I'll just add that there's also an article by Dr. Kevin Scoresby titled "How to Design a (POS) System that Everybody Hates" that discusses usability of POS systems and adds a few points to what people have already mentioned, such as:

1. Don't punish the employee for customer choices
2. Avoid creating conflicts with the real world
3. Avoid color coding (1 out of 10 males has a form of color blindness)

I've also discovered lots of helpful POS design tips at [POSDesigns.com](http://www.posdesigns.com).  One thing I found interesting is that by focusing too much on the **number** of button presses, you can actually impact speed--which is often a primary goal.  There's also a tip titled "Five Factors that Influence Speed" that I found helpful.

Good luck!

Kyle

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Scoresby was discussed above & is included in the points. Some feedback on your comments:

1. Colour coding is supported by Scoresby & Usability in general - but is recommened to be used in conjunction with other features for differentiating control groupings or states. Colour Blindness is approx. 1% for males for a particular types of colour blindness (red known as Protanopia; re-green known as Deuteranopia, Blue known as Tritanopia < 1%). POSDesign.com is Scoresby's site.
Thank you none the less.

Answer (score 1):

There are already some really good systems out there i.e. Tabtill for Win 8 http://www.tabtill.com or Shopkeep for iOS http://www.shopkeep.com. The fewest number of clicks your user need to do the better. As I am also involved in coding for such solutions and having worked with clients using various POS systems, some can be really frustrating. Remember watching cashiers in a bar tapping 10 times just to take payment for a couple of items, their fingers are hopelessly hovering over the screen trying to find the right colourful button. Keep it simple! Allow sorting of your visible product range, categorize them or use barcode reader. Keep at least 5% gap between buttons and don't let silly animations slow down your UI. Either invent your own or just copy what is already out there with your own twist.